# Mid-2015 - Borderlands weird screen texture when playing with the integrated Iris Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, games, gpu

I'm playing Borderlands 1 GOTY (Game of the year edition) from the App Store. Tried playing it only with the Iris Pro, instead of the Radeon R9 370X, and the performance is stunning.

However I get this weird pixel like texture on the screen. 
*It doesn't move or blink, and it doesn't seem to effect the HUD or menus.*

It seems to be "exactly" the same texture no matter what and it gets more detailed when I up the resolution.

I've tested Deus Ex and Bastion with the same setup and they have absolutely no problem. It seems like a OS X driver issue, I've seen graphics card's problems in the past and they aren't that stable or selective.

Can anyone confirm?

PS. Use [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io) to change to Integrated Only.

[image: In game]
[image: Respawning]
[image: In game 2]
[image: Scope]

Comment: did you fix it eventually?
I had it running perfectly fine, then deinstalled it, upgraded t El Capitan later, and installed it again. Now it looks like yours.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Emailed Borderlands support (Feral Interactive) and it seems to be a driver issue with the newer Intel GPUs on El Capitan. It doesn't happen in Borderlands 2 or any other game I tried so it might still be a Borderlands 1 problem. Their advice was to wait it out and see if newer OS X updates fix it and just play using the 370X. A bummer too, the Intel GPU on these machines seems to perform very well even on max settings.